# Turn value into 2<sup>value</sup>

Tags: algorithm, assembly, bit-manipulation

What is the fastest way of turning some value (stored in register) into 2 to the power of that value in assembly language? I think that some bitwise operations can be used. For example:

```
Value: 8
Result: 256 (2<sup>8</sup>)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, short answer: What you're looking for is a **left shift**.

in C and many other languages, your particular wish would be served by `1 << 8`.

You could do it in x86 assembler with `shl` but there's really no sane reason to do so since pretty much any compiler you come across is going to compile the code into the native shift instruction.